# Ten letter sequence made from vowels and five consonants

Tags: combinatorics

How many ten letter sequences can be made from five different vowels and five different consonants (selected from the twenty-one possible consonants? I am having a hard time approaching this problem. Can someone help me on how I should approach this problem and other like it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd break it into two steps.  First, how many ways are there to select your 5 consonants from the 21 possible consonants?  (I guess there is no choice involved for the vowels, you just use all 5 of them.)  Second, suppose you've selected your 5 consonants and you want to make a 10-letter sequence: how many ways can you arrange your 5 vowels and 5 consonants into a sequence of 10 letters?

The answer is the product of those two numbers.